# How to return None when parameter is double?

Tags: scala

Okay, so I am a beginner in Scala and I am required to return None in an if-else function. But I will always get this error:

`<console>:42: error: type mismatch;
 found   : None.type
 required: Double
              return None`

is there a way for me to solve this?

update: these are my codes

```
def get_grid_parameters(params: Double): Double = {


if (params == "edge_lating") {
   return grid_hex_edge_length_latlng
}

   else if (params == "grid_bottom_left_lat") {
       return grid_bottom_left_lat
}
   else if (params == "grid_bottom_left_lng") {
       return grid_bottom_left_lng
}
   else if (params == "edge_metres") {
       return latlng_diff_to_metres(grid_hex_edge_length_latlng)
}
   else if (params == "hex_height") {
       return 0.002598076211353316
}
   else if (params == "increment_lng") {
       return 0.002250
}
   else if (params == "increment_lat") {
       return 0.001299038105676658
}
   else {
       print("Invalid parameters!")
       return None
}

}
```

Comment: Where is your function (show me code as well)?

Comment: @pamu look at the update

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the return type of the function to `Option[Double]`. `return` is optional in Scala. `params` should be `String`

```
def get_grid_parameters(params: String): Option[Double] = {


if (params == "edge_lating") {
   Some(grid_hex_edge_length_latlng)
}

   else if (params == "grid_bottom_left_lat") {
       Some(grid_bottom_left_lat)
}
   else if (params == "grid_bottom_left_lng") {
       Some(grid_bottom_left_lng)
}
   else if (params == "edge_metres") {
       Some(latlng_diff_to_metres(grid_hex_edge_length_latlng))
}
   else if (params == "hex_height") {
       Some(0.002598076211353316)
}
   else if (params == "increment_lng") {
       Some(0.002250)
}
   else if (params == "increment_lat") {
       Some(0.001299038105676658)
}
   else {
       print("Invalid parameters!")
       return None
}

}
```

You can use pattern matching its more clear

```
def getGridParams(param: String): Option[Double] = param match {
 case "edge_lating" => Some(grid_hex_edge_length_latlng)
 case "grid_bottom_left_lat" => Some(grid_bottom_left_lat)
 case "grid_bottom_left_lng" => Some(grid_bottom_left_lng)
 case "edge_metres" => Some(latlng_diff_to_metres(grid_hex_edge_length_latlng))
 case "hex_height" =>  Some(0.002598076211353316)
 case "increment_lng" =>  Some(0.002250)
 case "increment_lat" => Some(0.001299038105676658)
 case _ => None
}
```

**explanation:**

In Scala no value is captured using `None` and some value case is modelled using `Some(value)`. `Option` is the super type None and Some. So Some and None values can be directly assigned to the variable whose type if `Option[T]`.

Example:

```
scala> val a: Option[Int] = None
a: Option[Int] = None

scala> val a: Option[Int] = Some(1)
a: Option[Int] = Some(1)

scala> def toInt(str: String): Option[Int] = {
     |   if (str.forall(_.isDigit)) Some(str.toInt)
     |   else None
     | }
toInt: (str: String)Option[Int]

scala> toInt("123a")
res0: Option[Int] = None

scala> toInt("123")
res1: Option[Int] = Some(123)
```

In the above example if string contains chars we return None if not we return Some(value). Look at the return type of `toInt` which is Option[Int]

Comment: I got a warning which states that "comparing values of types Double and String using `==' will always yield false"

Comment: @nsbr11 added pattern matching solution Please check

Comment: thank you for the pattern matching solution too! makes it much more clearer :)